# Pyspark ImportError: No module named spark_df_profiling

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to use `spark_df_profiling` in pyspark databricks environment. I am getting the following error.

```
> pip install spark_df_profiling
```

```py
from datetime import datetime
import spark_df_profiling
df = sql("select * from ab.data").cache()
```

```
ImportError: No module named 'spark_df_profiling'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2036534138125494> in <module>()
      1 from datetime import datetime
----> 2 import spark_df_profiling
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Do you run on cluster or standalone env ?

Answer (score 0):

For Databricks, it may be best to use the `dbutils.library.installPyPI` method for installing packages.

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("spark_df_profiling")

import spark_df_profiling
```